# Run bat file with npx command in visual code

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-code, npx

I am getting this error in visual studio code:

[image]

The above error shows whenever I launch my progam due to this launch.json script:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach using Process Id",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "preLaunchTask": "kill_process"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "preLaunchTask": "kill_process"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json"
        },
        {
            "label": "kill_process",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": ".\\script\\kill_process.bat"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the content of kill_process.bat file:

```
npx kill-port 8000
```

However, when I run the script from powershell it executes without any problem, here is the proof:

[image]

Does someone perhaps know how I can run the kill_process.bat file without any error in visual studio code?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes: "_preLaunchTask - to launch a task before the start of a debug session, set this attribute to the label of a task specified in tasks.json (in the workspace's .vscode folder). Or, this can be set to ${defaultBuildTask} to use your default build task._" Where is your tasks.json?

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: I can't reproduce the logs because strangely the problem is now fixed, and I did not do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely it is now fixed but I don't know how because now I am reading this in my console in visual studio code:

```
 *  Executing task: .\script\kill_process.bat 


D:\documents\leerplek\python\Wpark>npx kill-port 8000 
Process on port 8000 killed
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```